# Error to deploy Landscape via Juju Gui "Status: error - hook failed: "install" IP address: none Public address: none"

Tags: landscape

My Lab:

- 1VM for Maas + Juju (both installed via ppa stable) on Ubuntu
  16.04Lts;
- 1VM for Juju Gui with Ubuntu 16.04Lts;
- 4VM for Landscape with Ubuntu 16.04Lts;

Trying to deploy all components, one by one, on each vm dedicated to the service.

[image]

I've received that issue,

```
Status: error - hook failed: "config-changed"
IP address: none
Public address: none
```

seeing its log

```
juju debug-log --include unit-postgresql-7 --replay
```

the only error is that:

```
ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation hook "install" failed: exit status 1
```

[image]

The command

```
 $: juju status
```

reports these lines

[image]

I've also try to deploy MariaDB and the error also in this case is the same, here is the screen

[image]

What does that error mean? Where I've wrong?Anyone can help me?

Comment: anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi, you need log information.  'hook failed' is the equivalent of 'script failed' but without any output.  To get output, you'll need to examine `juju debug-log`, but more likely, go over to the failed `postgresql` unit: `juju ssh postgresql/0`, and examine the `/var/log/juju` directory to see what the actual problem is.