# Is the Ubuntu OpenStack Autopilot is still a valid solution on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to follow the official instructions of OpenStack Autopilot, but when I try to run the command to deploy Autopilot it suggests that I use conjure-up. Can I use conjure-up to install the Juju GUI, Landscape and OpenStack on a virtual environment based on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you want to run Openstack Autopilot because you want to check out what Openstack looks and smells like.  If I am correct, you don't want autopilot, or to install juju manually, or any of that.  If you try to follow those (now outdated) guides you'll get stuck with versions of Landscape, Juju, and conjure-up that don't work with each other.

So, the best thing to do is to start with a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04.2.  I do this on my laptop all the time, or on a virtual machine running in VirtualBox, KVM/libvirt, AWS, vmware, Hyper-V, etc.  Doesn't matter.  Once you have a working 16.04.2 installation, run:

```
snap install conjure-up --classic
```

After installation, run

```
conjure-up
```

and select "Openstack with NovaLXD".  Most of the prompts you can just accept default answers.  At the end of the installation, you'll get a url to access your Openstack Horizon console.  Something like:

http://10.0.8.33/horizon/auth/login/?next=/horizon/identity/

And you can run (from the host)...

```
juju gui
```

...to get to the juju console.  Another command that will be initially helpful is:

```
lxc list
```

This will show you all the containers (about 15 of them) that are running your Openstack installation.

Using the conjure-up snap, you'll get the most simplified, latest, greatest version of Openstack built around Canonical's ecosystem (Juju, LXD, etc.)

Comment: yes you right, but the project Openstack Autopilot has been used to deploy that on more nodes in an Juju environment with Landscape, Jujugui and Openstack, while conjure-up is used to install only Openstack on only one node. To have also Landscape deployed?

Comment: There are version compatibility issues with current stable Landscape, Maas and Juju. Im not at my computer now to lookup specifics. But its not exactly "auto"-pilot. Thats why i was recommending Conjure up via snap for a demonstration installation.

Comment: I've opened a post (http://askubuntu.com/questions/886533/error-to-deploy-landscape-via-juju-gui-status-error-hook-failed-install-i)  aboud the deploy of Landscape on Juju Gui but any solution solution. I've already tested conjure-up for Openstack on 16.04 and it's work, but I'd like to see also Landscape with it.