# Is it possible to deploy an openstack clustor with Autopilot, while not using Landscape

Tags: server, openstack-autopilot

quick question.

Is it possibly to deploy an OpenStack Cloud with OpenStack Autopilot without the use of Canonical Landscape?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autopilot requires Landscape.  For a simplified install of OpenStack (for testing, development, etc.), you can use conjure-up.  Please see my answer in this linked question for more details:

[But Ubuntu Openstack Autopilot is still a validate solution on Ubuntu 14.04Lts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891687/but-ubuntu-openstack-autopilot-is-still-a-validate-solution-on-ubuntu-14-04lts/891707#891707)